# Will Quasar and Adam Warlock appear in the Guardians of the Galaxy movie?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, guardians-of-the-galaxy-1

In the released concept art for the Guardians of the Galaxy movie we see Drax, Groot, Star-Lord, Rocket Raccoon and Gamora.

[image]

However in the comics, Quasar and Adam Warlock are members of the Guardians as well.  Do we know if they will be appearing in the film, or have they been downsized out for whatever reason?

Comment: They did cameo Adam Warlocks cocoon in the Collectors "museum" thing.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### No. Currently the concept art you are showing is all of the Guardians who will be used for the movie. The team includes [Drax the Destroyer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drax_the_Destroyer), [Groot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Groot), [Star-Lord](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star-Lord), [Rocket Raccoon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rocket_Raccoon) and [Gamora](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamora). Drax and Gamora are indeed members of the Guardians; [Thanos](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thanos), Ronan the Accuser and Nebula also make an appearance as the primary villains.

[image]

There was no indication why Quasar or Adam Warlock were not included, but likely the answer is a superhero team that is too large may be difficult to deal with on camera. Consider all three of these heroes has the potential for complex visual effects, where guns and martial arts are the mainstay of the current choices. The visual effects for Groot and Rocket Racoon will be relatively simply in comparison.

**At Comic-Con 2012, [Kevin Feige](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kevin_Feige) revealed the following:**

> Kevin Feige announced that "Guardians of the Galaxy" is set for release on August 1, 2014. Feige revealed the space-faring super-team will include the characters Star-Lord, Rocket Raccoon, Groot, Gamora and Drax the Destroyer.  The inclusion of Gamora and Drax makes it highly likely Thanos, seen at the end title scene in "The Avengers," will be somehow involved in the film's storyline.  The god-like super villain has a long history with the "Guardians" in Marvel Comics' lore, but a direct connection to Gamora and Drax. **--HitFix > ['Guardians of the Galaxy' will feature Star-Lord, Rocket Raccoon, Groot, Gamora and Drax](http://www.hitfix.com/news/guardians-of-the-galaxy-will-feature-star-lord-rocket-raccoon-groot-gamora-and-drax)**

Answer (score 4):

Adam Warlock did not appear in the first *Guardians of the Galaxy* movie (2014), but he finally made his appearance in *Guardians of the Galaxy Vol. 3* (2023). He was first hinted at in the post-credits scene of *Guardians of the Galaxy Vol. 2* (2017), as one of the Sovereign.

As for Quasar, the MCU has not introduced Wendell Vaughn, the original Quasar, yet. However, [Phyla-Vell](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Phyla), who inherited the Quasar mantle in the comics, made her appearance in *Guardians of the Galaxy Vol. 3*.